# SonarQube analyzer by user

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to show a history of code improvement done by a specific user in SonarQube (Community Edition/Developer Edition/Enterprise Edition/Data Center Edition)?

Obs: The SCM is enable in settings.

Long explanation:

We have 12 developers, but the software is legacy one.

The goal: to improve the quality code generated, so that it can grow (scale) in the future without problems.

As an incentive we are looking to use SonarQube not only as a quality meter but as a means to reward those who have contributed most to quality.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but this question is interesting ! Could you give some examples of what you want ?

Comment: I add new info. @Julian.

Comment: Ok thanks. It would be interesting to develop these ideas, but SOF is not the best option. If you have some mode advanced ideas (which criteria would you use to users, etc.), I encourage you to open a new thread on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube.